# Check checkbox if selectbox changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im breaking my head over this piece.
How do I check a checkbox if a user changes an option next to it.
This is nested in a loop to display a checkbox for users and how many guests they bring along.

Comment: show us what u have tried!

Comment: I have no idea how to get this to work.
Im totally new to JQuery and i dont like asking for code, but im on a dead end.

Comment: at the least share your sample html

Comment: Displaying the relevant source code would help. "if a user changes an option **next to it**" Next to what? "**This** is nested in a loop" What is? You need to give us something to debug before we can tell you where you're going wrong and how to fix it. No source code = nothing to work with. It really is that simple.

Answer (score 0):

You would go about it to by binding an `.on('change', function() {})` eventlistener to the select, inside the handler you test `$(this).val()` whether the condition is met. And if it is met you fetch your checkbox with a selector and put `.prop('checked', true)`.

That's the gist of it, if you need any more refined help, we need source code or at least an html structur to work with.